# Docker ps prints empty list

Tags: docker

How can I see the list of running containers?

```
sh-4.2$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

sh-4.2$ docker rm filebeat
Error response from daemon: You cannot remove a running container 998f73f25e997ba9838df85e8a83b05df9f2c713580ac3e183655c8241e4e84b. Stop the container before attempting removal or force remove
```

I thought `docker ps` did, but it shows an empty list.

Comment: Maybe you updated docker while a container was running similar to: https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1324655.html

Comment: @A.K. This is likely to be the cause of the problem... Thanks